# Get duplicate values from Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure, duplicates, azure-storage

How can I query on the `Azure Table Storage` for duplicate values?

Suppose the table contains a column named 'LastName' and there are a few lastnames that equal to each other. How can I query on that without knowing or having that specific `string` that holds the lastname value?

**Edit**
An example would be:

```
Partitionkey RowKey LastName
1            1      Smith
1            2      Smith
1            3      Smith
1            3      MILLER
1            3      WILLIAMS
```

In this case, I'd like to get all records where Smith is the last name, because they are duplicates.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: See my question, it's edited with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb: queries that do not include the `PartitionKey` or `RowKey` will not perform very well.

I assume your `LastName` column is neither Partition- nor RowKey. In that case you only have bad options. The way Table Storage works is that entitios of a Partition are stored close together, so the fastest queries are those that include the Partition Key of the entities you are looking for. Since you cannot build indexes on any other columns, all queries that do not include the RowKey will be partition-scans, i.e. not perform well at all because all rows of that partition must be analyzed.

In your case, if you are looking for all those columns that include duplicate values, your best bet will likely be to just query everything and look for duplicates locally.

I don't think you can create a table storage query that would return the results. As far as I know, there is no such thing as `select … where count(select duplicates) > 1` – and even if so, that query would be very slow. Unless we're talking about huge amounts of data, simply querying everything and filtering locally would likely perform better.

As I said, you only have bad options. That's because Table Storage wasn't designed for queries like this. Unlike SQL tables, Table Storage tables should be designed with queries in mind, i.e. you should know how you're gonna query the table before you design it.

Your second option would be to migrate to Azure SQL, where such queries are no problem at all. Azure SQL is very different form Table Storage though, so it's questionable whether it fits your requirements.

**Edit:** One way you can optimize the query-everything solution would be to only return the LastNames of your entities (+ Partition/RowKey or whatever else you need). This way the amount of data that is being sent can potentially be reduced by quite a bit. [Here's](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/#query-entity-properties) an article about query projection that explains this technique in detail.

Comment: Just a clarification: Queries without row keys will result in *partition* scans, not *table* scans.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the query will be performed in a certain partition. Just no rowkey's.

Comment: @David Makogon: you're right, I should have clarified that when I said "table" scan. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Quoter: even then, there's currently no way to create such a query. There are ways how you can work around this, but they heavily depend on your application - we'd need more context to help you. For example, you could store lookup data in a redundant way, e.g. store an additonal row with LastName as RowKey and a count as value, and increase or decrease that count on insert and delete operations. This heavily complicates DML operations, not to mention the synchronization risks, but it would boost your queries enormously. There are a lot of pitfalls and if you have more inserts / deletes than

Comment: [cont.] queries then it won't even be worth it. I'd avoid doing this if there are other options, but since storage is cheap and if you do perform way more queries than DML operations, such an approach **might** be worth it. Then again, if SQL Azure is an option for you, I'd prefer it. Do you have to perform many similar queries like this? Maybe you could look into SQL Azure and sharding instead of Table Storage if you absolutely need these queries?

Comment: I see.. Yes these queries are needed. We choose for the Azure Table Storage because the data that comes in is a lot for an SQL database to handle. Just me running this locally I get like 200 records in less than 2 seconds (and it keeps coming in) and this is just from 1 feed. The question about finding duplicates was just to simplify the question. Marked as answered, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Quoter: no problem, happy to help. Since you're dealing with so much data, it might be worth it to look at key-value stores like [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [Lucene](https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/). I know that Lucene can be run on Azure instances (it relies on blob storage) and think that Redis can work too... sadly I have no experience with these services. But if you have a lot of different queries and huge amounts of data, it may be worth it to take a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

The query to fetch all records should be

```
PartitionKey eq 'Your PartitionKey' and LastName eq 'Smith'
```

unless I'm missing something.

You would also need to take table continuation token into consideration as well. See this thread for more details: [Copy all Rows to another Table in Azure Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376087/copy-all-rows-to-another-table-in-azure-table-storage/). As @enzi mentioned, there's no `Select * from table where ...` functionality is available in table storage.

Comment: I know that this query would work, but my question stated that I don't have the knowledge of which last name's are duplicates. The query itself should find out which last name is a duplicate. So than it seems that this is not possible?